# Java: reading file from remote path

Tags: java, remote-server, samba

In Java, I would to read file from remote path into string. Local point and remote point are on the same network. Local point is Windows, remote point is Linux.
To read file from local path I use:

```
filecontent = new Scanner(new File(...local path...)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

Instead, for remote path I found more solutions that doesn't work, for example:

1. File(..remote path..) as **"\\remote host\remote dir\..\test.txt"**
2. **File(new URI("file:///..remote path.."));**
3. Mounting path in drive Z: and read as **new File("z:\test.txt");**

I found one other solution like **JCIFS Samba library** that I'll use if there isn't other ways. First, I would ask you if there's another way that use only **new File(..)**.

Thank you for your attention.

**UPDATE 1:**

I get remote path from my Oracle db. Now in my table there's "z:\test.xml".
Using **new File("z:\test.xml");** the stacktrace is:

```
Java.io.FileNotFoundException: z:\test.xml (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at it.latraccia.aruba.client.ClientFatturaElettronicaAruba.runClientFatturaElettronicaAruba(ClientFatturaElettronicaAruba.java:106)
    at it.traccia.tracciaHub.TracciaHub.doGet(TracciaHub.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

line 106 of ClientFatturaElettronicaAruba.runClientFatturaElettronicaAruba(ClientFatturaElettronicaAruba.java:106:

```
filebase64 = new Scanner(new File(responsegetparaminviafattura.getFilePath())).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

**UPDATE 2**: *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*

My web application run under Tomcat 8.0 with Java 1.8

***(see method "doGet")***

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Test() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}   

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    try {       
        File f = new File("z:\\test.xml");

        if(f.exists()) {
            request.setAttribute("ret",f.toString());
        }
        else {
            request.setAttribute("ret","file not exist");
        }

        visualizzaJsp(request,response,"/index.jsp");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        request.setAttribute("ret","IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();            
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        request.setAttribute("ret","ServletException");
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }       

}   

public void visualizzaJsp (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,String pathDispatcher)throws IOException, ServletException{

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher =this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(pathDispatcher);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

}
```

}

The output in my index.jsp is "**file not exist**".

Comment: Well then I would do some experiments like: directly logging into that server to check what drives are visible. Or: writing Java test code that queries the file system and puts as much debug data into that response as possible. Just develop some curiosity and start testing theories systematically. You don't need other people for that :-)

Comment: Sorry but it isn't so simple, on the other side there's a cluster with more nodes. I think that can be a handshake problem between Tomcat and cluster (with shared folder of course).

Comment: Well; but in the end, your java code is executed exactly in *one* jvm running on *one* node. And *there* it is trying to access the *local* file system. And it doesn't make much sense to add "more complexity" until you have a clear understanding why that operation is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Here; your option 3:

```
Mounting path in drive Z: and read as new File("z:\test.txt");
```

That should definitely work; but probably you need

```
new File("z:\\test.txt");
```

instead!

You see, in your last example, there is no "visible" difference between a local file; and a remote one. To java, it is just a "file" on some windows drive. And then you simply have to provide a file name that is valid on windows; and "\" typically needs to escaped to "\" !

Given your updates: the exception `Java.io.FileNotFoundException: z:\test.xml` is pretty self-explaining - that file doesn't exist.

That is why I suggested to create a **real** minimal example; in other words: try to run something like

```
 public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     new File("z:\\test.xml");
   }
 }
```

and see what happens then. And please note: at least your updated question is **still** using "\" instead of "\". So maybe: when those strings are coming out of the database, you have to **rework** them, before using them as input to the File() constructor!

Comment: Sorry. I updated my question with UPDATE 1. Thank you

Comment: See UPDATE 2 with my example code and output "file not exist"